# Oracle - Return rows with max_date duplicate

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, date, duplicates

I have the following table structure:
`car_id number PK, rent_date date, return_date date`.

The table is very inconsistent and I would like to retrieve the `car_id,max(return_date)` but only if the max(return_date) is duplicated. Is it possible?

For example:

```
 2    12/12/12  13/12/12
 2    11/12/12  13/12/12
```

The return_date is duplicated for the car_id 2 so it should be returned by the query.

Thanks !!

Comment: Your question is not clear. If car_id is PK then how there can be multiple entries for one car. and also how one car can rent on different dates but returned on same dates?

Comment: It seams car_id can not be the PK!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT T.car_id, max(T.return_date) From TableName T
Group by T.car_id, T.return_date
Having COUNT(*) > 1
```

If Time part of Date is not desired in comparison, you may use:

In Oracle:

```
SELECT T.car_id, max(T.return_date) From TableName T
Group by T.car_id, TRUNC(T.return_date)
Having COUNT(*) > 1
```

In MySql:

```
SELECT T.car_id, max(T.return_date) From TableName T
Group by T.car_id, DATE(T.return_date)
Having COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: Sorry about the example. I tried the query above but it seems to be returning duplicate rows, regardless its the max date or not.

Comment: Heres another example:
car id 88
returned dates: 04/04/11 7:26:18 PM, 
                04/04/11 7:26:18 PM,
                12/12/07 10:10:14 AM,
                12/12/07 10:01:45 AM,
                30/05/2014 07:44:41 AM

This car_id is beeing retrieved using the queries above but it shouldn´t since the max_date isn´t duplicate

Comment: I didn't understand the problem  correctly, you may see http://sqlfiddle.com/ and fill a sample then give us the link.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7d8cd1/10

With the current query it is returning only the 07 jan date, which is correct. However when i run this query on the original table using oracle 11g it didnt seem to work. Is there any difference between mysql and oracle on the use of count+max within the same query ?

Comment: No, there is no difference, it is standard sql. the Time part of date may cause the problem. did you tried the second query that containes TRUNC function?

Comment: Yes! It works fine in oracle if i dont use the count(*) function. It retrieves all the max_date regardless if its duplicated or not. When i add the count(*) clause it retrieves all duplicate regardless it is the max_date or not. idk what i could be doing wrong. Maybe the rent_date is causing it ?